# Random Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am working on a game. At some places, sometimes I receive a segmentation fault and at all other times the code works properly. If I run the game again (after receiving segmentation fault) it recovers back (without any code changes) and runs fine. But after some time again this happens.

I tried debugging it using GDB. I got the following information:

1. there is a function call : func(&s.x), where s is a structure and x is its member of type int. The address (&s.x) is 0xb3456721
2. In function func the value received in the argument is 0xb.
3. The program crashes saying memory at 0xb cannot be accessed. When I print the variable using GDB, I again receive memory cannot be accessed.

Any ideas Why this would happen?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: We'd have a lot more ideas if there is a code.

Comment: What is the declaration of `func`?  Do you have the prototype included every place you use it?

Comment: You're going to have to share some code where you think the failure is.

Comment: `The program crashes saying memory at 0xb cannot be accessed.` That is precisely the reason for `SegFault`. Your code tries to write outside its allowed segment. It may happen when you try to dereference an uninitialized pointer or a dangling pointer.

Comment: I'll bet that `offsetof(S, x)` is `0xb`, just like the address seen in `func`. That means that somewhere a null pointer is being dereferenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A program that crashes sometimes but not other times when given identical input has a non-deterministic data source in it.  Usually the source is an uninitialized variable or block of memory, but it could be dependence on a timestamp, process ID, or other source of input from the system that varies.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) successfully before on Linux to debug non-deterministic behavior caused by uninitialized variables.

Here's the `valgrind` command I use, your program and options should follow

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes --track-origins=yes -v
```

If you are running on Windows, take a look at this answer for `valgrind` substitutes

[Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Is your program multi-threaded?  One source of non-determinism is a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing).

Answer (score 0):

Since the C++ tag is present, but you are saying you are calling then function with: `func(&s.x)`, then given that `func` says it received `0xb` in its argument parameter leads me to believe `s` is actually an improperly initialized reference. For example, consider:

```
struct foo {
    char a[12];
    int x;
};

void func (int *x) {
    *x = 0;
}

int main () {
    foo *sp = (foo *)-1;
    foo &s = *sp;
    func(&s.x);
}
```

It is impossible to diagnose the precise nature of your problem because you have not provided enough information.